# Amazon LEX is returning error with iOS Swift

Tags: amazon-web-services, swift3, xamarin.ios, amazon-cognito, amazon-lex

Im trying to integrate Amazon LEX into my application. Initially i added the Amazon cognito and from that i got the Cognito Id. Next when i tried to communicate with the LEX is returning an error saying like this

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSLexErrorDomain Code=0 "null" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=null, NSLocalizedFailureReason=AccessDeniedException:http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.coral.service/}
```

AppDelegate Code :

```
{
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose
        let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: “given the Id”)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration


        credentialProvider.getIdentityId().continueWith(block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in

            if (task.error != nil)
            {
                print("Error: " + task.error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            else
            {
                let cognitoId = task.result!
                print("Cognito Id is, \(cognitoId)")
            }

            return task

        })

        let chatConfig = AWSLexInteractionKitConfig.defaultInteractionKitConfig(withBotName: "BookTrip", botAlias: "Chatting")
        AWSLexInteractionKit.register(with: configuration!, interactionKitConfiguration: chatConfig, forKey: "AWSLexVoiceButton")

        chatConfig.autoPlayback = false
        //AWSLexInteractionKit.register(with: configuration!, interactionKitConfiguration: chatConfig, forKey: "chatConfig")
    return true
    }
```

The viewController code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       (self.voiceButton)?.delegate = self
   // (self.voiceButton as AWSLexVoiceButton).delegate = self


    }

    func voiceButton(_ button: AWSLexVoiceButton, on response: AWSLexVoiceButtonResponse) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            // `inputranscript` is the transcript of the voice input to the operation
            print("Input Transcript: \(String(describing: response.inputTranscript))")
            if let inputTranscript = response.inputTranscript {
                self.input.text = "\"\(inputTranscript)\""
            }
            print("on text output \(String(describing: response.outputText))")
            self.output.text = response.outputText
        })
    }

    public func voiceButton(_ button: AWSLexVoiceButton, onError error: Error) {
        print("error \(error)")
    }
```

Do i need to pass the cognito Id along with LEX. Could anyone please help me what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out the solution. The issue was with IAM permission. You have to attach permission policy in IAM console. Hope this help you.

Comment: which permission ? Stuck in same place

Comment: IAM permission in console. i,e login into the amazon portal and add IAM permission to your bot

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the IAM policy associated to role of the Cognito Identity Pool doesn't have AmazonLexFullAccess permissions. To add the permissions, see the following steps:

1. Go to edit identity pool, check which role you have for both unauthorises and authorises.
2. Select IAM service then search for Roles and then select that role which you have asign to unauthorises and authorises.
3. Click on the particular role and attach policy of AmazonLexFullAccess.

Hope this steps will help you.